# Need an SVG workaround

Tags: javascript, html, xml, animation, svg

I'm recreating blueprints as SVGs, as can be seen in this [Pen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/OWrxMO). I'm obviously not finished, so the code is a bit sloppy right now since I've been experimenting with different workarounds in vain.

One of the effects I have implemented is rooms will `fill` with an `opacity: 0.5` if hovered.

Initially the doors consisted of only two elements (a `path` or line that rotates, and a `path` whose `stroke-dashoffset` is animated) to achieve the effect of the doors shutting and then opening, so, if a room has doors that protrude outwards and is hovered, there will be "empty" space within that (or those) door frame(s).

Therefore, in order to `fill` the empty space within the door "frames" I simply created a closed path, overlaid it on top of the initial two elements, got rid of its `stroke`, and gave it a `fill`. The issue with this workaround, though, is that if you rotate the door's `fill`, which is also set to an `opacity: 0.5`, in tandem with the closing door, when the door is completely closed that part of the room's `fill` of course becomes a darker colour (i.e. `opacity: 0.5` + `opacity: 0.5`).

So my next idea was to create a "mask" element. The "mask" element is another quarter-circle (BLUE in the codepen), which mirrors the area of the door "frame", and also rotates in tandem with the door to eventually obscure the door "frame's" fill. If the doors of some rooms weren't so close to other walls, this would be an adequate solution, yet I've designed the SVG so that it will appear perfectly crisp at a `scale(1)` for mobile.

The next workaround I devised was similar to the last, but instead of using a mirrored quarter-circle I tried using a `rect`angle (GREEN in the codepen), which I would rotate while increasing and then decreasing the width. The issue I've run into with this workaround is that, for whatever reason, the `rect`angle seemingly increases its `width` outwards in both directions from its center, and also `transition`s its `x` position despite its `transform-origin` being set to `100% 100%`. Notably, I have played around quite a bit with the values, and have gotten it to work almost adequately, so that it obscures most of the quarter-circle door "frame"; nonetheless, I'm fairly certain that I would have to continually adjust these values any time the blueprint is `scale`d, and there didn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the particular values that "worked".

Another idea I had was to decrease the size of doors, but I'm afraid that by doing so the doors will become borderline illegible at `scale(1)`.

**Has anybody ever run into this issue before?**

**Is anybody aware of any workarounds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion for the first strategy you attempted. You say that you got a darker color where the door fill rotated into and over top of the floor fill because of the opacity overlap. That will happen when you apply the opacity to each element separately. However, if you can group the two elements together and then apply the opacity to the group, there is no darker color where the two shapes actually overlap. The code below demonstrates this. The left-hand grouping of shapes has opacity applied to each of the two elements. The right-hand grouping of shapes is drawn identically except that the opacity is applied to the entire group. Can you group your elements this way in order to be able to apply the opacity to a group element?

```html
<svg width='400'>
  <g transform='translate(0,0)'>
    <path d='M100,90 L100,40 A50,50 0 0 0 50,90 Z' transform='rotate(45, 100, 90)' opacity='0.5'/>
    <path d='M100,10 H200 V110 H100 Z' opacity='0.5'/>
  </g>
  <g transform='translate(200,0)' opacity='0.5'>
    <path d='M100,90 L100,40 A50,50 0 0 0 50,90 Z' transform='rotate(45, 100, 90)'/>
    <path d='M100,10 H200 V110 H100 Z'/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The situation is a bit more complex when a door belongs to two different rooms. In such a case, for the room that the door opens *out* of, you can just add the door fill to the floor fill as shown above. However, for the room that the door opens *into*, you need to subtract the shape of the door fill from the floor fill. To do that, first create an inverse of a door fill, i.e.:

```html
<svg width="200">
    <path id="doorFillPath"
          transform="translate(120,100)"
          d="                                       M0,0 h-50 a50,50 0 0 1 50,-50 Z"
          />
</svg>

<svg width="200">
    <path id="doorFillInvPath"
          transform="translate(120,100)"
          d="M-1000,-1000 v2000 h2000 v-2000 h-2000 M0,0 h-50 a50,50 0 0 1 50,-50 Z"
          />
</svg>
```

That requires doubling up the code for the shape of the door fill, as the door shape is placed part-way into the `d` attribute of the inverse shape and thus can't be dynamically copied using `<defs>` and `<use>`, but at least the `d` path component for the door fill shape (i.e. the part starting with `"M0,0..."`) is identical in both places, making for relatively easy manual copying or even, with just a bit of attribute retrieval and string manipulation, some automatic copying.

Then, for each door opening *out* of a room, add the door fill path to the floor fill path as shown above, but for each door opening *into* a room, cut the door fill *inverse* path out of the floor fill using a `<clipPath>` element and a `clip-path` attribute as shown below.

Note that, with this strategy, there can be a single door fill shape in the `<defs>` section with each `<use>` copy transformed in the main body of the image, but you have to make each individual copy of the door *inverse* fill shape within the `<defs>` section, transform each copy there, and give each copy there an appropriate id. It still seems like a workable solution to me, though.

```css
.floor {
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
.floor:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#walls, #door {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<svg style="position: absolute; z-index: 100;" width="100%" height="100%">

  <defs>
    <path id="doorFillInvPath" d="M-1000,-1000 v2000 h2000 v-2000 h-2000
                               M0,0 h-50 a50,50 0 0 1 50,-50 Z"/>
    <path id="doorFillPath" d="M0,0 h-50 a50,50 0 0 1 50,-50 Z"/>
    <clipPath id="doorFillInv1" transform="translate(210,100) rotate(45)">
      <use href="#doorFillInvPath"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="doorFillInv2" transform="translate(210,200) rotate(60)">
      <use href="#doorFillInvPath"/>
    </clipPath>
    <line id="door" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-50"/>
  </defs>

  <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(10,40)">
    <g class="floor">
      <use href="#doorFillPath" transform="translate(210,200) rotate(60)"/>
      <path id="room1" d="M10,10 h200 v250 h-200 z" stroke="none" clip-path="url(#doorFillInv1)"/>
    </g>
    <g class="floor">
      <use href="#doorFillPath" transform="translate(210,100) rotate(45)"/>
      <path id="room2" d="M210,10 h150 v100 h50 v150 h-200 z" stroke="none" clip-path="url(#doorFillInv2)"/>
    </g>

    <use href="#door" transform="translate(210,100) rotate(-45)"/>
    <use href="#door" transform="translate(210,200) rotate(60)"/>
    <path id="walls" d="M210,10 h150 v100 h50 v150 h-200 v-60 m0,-50 v-50 m0,-50 v-40 h-200 v250 h200"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<p>Mouse over (i.e. hover over) each room to see the floor fills.</p>
<p style="color: #ccc;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nunc neque, molestie quis erat in, dignissim pretium nulla. Maecenas eget pretium purus. Aliquam interdum at dolor id sagittis. Phasellus risus dui, consectetur ac tortor ac, dignissim consequat felis. Maecenas lacinia ac arcu in porttitor. Duis aliquam maximus quam, vel venenatis dui. Quisque placerat ligula sit amet finibus vestibulum. Suspendisse tristique pharetra eleifend. Fusce nisl lectus, gravida vitae elit sed, vehicula condimentum orci. Sed dapibus pharetra odio ultricies egestas. Quisque pretium vehicula ante in commodo. Nulla eget turpis ac sem tristique posuere ac non diam. Aliquam at pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nunc neque, molestie quis erat in, dignissim pretium nulla. Maecenas eget pretium purus. Aliquam interdum at dolor id sagittis. Phasellus risus dui, consectetur ac tortor ac, dignissim consequat felis. Maecenas lacinia ac arcu in porttitor. Duis aliquam maximus quam, vel venenatis dui. Quisque placerat ligula sit amet finibus vestibulum. Suspendisse tristique pharetra eleifend. Fusce nisl lectus, gravida vitae elit sed, vehicula condimentum orci. Sed dapibus pharetra odio ultricies egestas. Quisque pretium vehicula ante in commodo. Nulla eget turpis ac sem tristique posuere ac non diam. Aliquam at pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nunc neque, molestie quis erat in, dignissim pretium nulla. Maecenas eget pretium purus. Aliquam interdum at dolor id sagittis. Phasellus risus dui, consectetur ac tortor ac, dignissim consequat felis.</p>
```

Comment: OMG!!! i'm pretty certain i can group them! you're a life saver. if i can indeed group them, i'll mark this as the answer. you sure one element wouldn't clip the other if they're both paths? i'm still new to SVG. this is basically the first real project i've ever used it. only messed around with it for one other personal thing a long time ago.

Comment: I changed the `rect` elements in my demo to `path` elements just to show that this approach works with all `path` elements.

Comment: it's been my pleasure

Comment: hm... i might actually run into a minor problem when the door belongs to two rooms, so to speak. i guess i can just either <defs> and <use> and use another class. shouldn't be a biggie tho

Comment: or nevermind, i only need to group it with the room it actually belongs to, and then only apply the rotation when the room to which the door belongs is hovered. i've been staring at code for wayyy too long with way too little sleep lol

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example and discussion of one possible approach to using doors that are shared between rooms.

Comment: I actually didn't encounter any issues and was able to accomplish the the two possible routes that I had in mind. Anyways, thanks again. Hopefully your modified answer will help somebody who finds their self in a similar scenario in the future. <3

Comment: I forgot that the reason I was staying away from `<defs><path></defs><use></use>` was because then i'd have to reposition and recalculate everything in relation to the document, so it'd get a bit tricky when trying to figure out the `transform-origins`. or is it only the `x` and `y` positions that become relative to the document?

Comment: No problem at all if you're using a different solution to your problem, and, yes, I do hope that a future reader might find this helpful. However, depending on what your strategy currently is, you may want to at least take my extended answer apart. I do think it provides a reasonably uncomplicated method to dynamically control multiple doors. For example, my door fill in `<defs>` has its "hinge" at the origin (0,0) and only requires translating that hinge to its appropriate absolute location with a simple `x` & `y` translation & simple rot'n. In any case, your animated blueprint was very cool!

Comment: tbh i hadn't even read your modifications since i had what i needed and am already falling behind schedule. i will now though. i looked at the one code snippet and i LOVE how how you did it--deliberately or unintentionally--without the momentum lines. i didn't even think of it, but there really isn't a use for the momentum lines as long as you have the "door frame fills". anyways, ya ill read it now and let u know

Comment: not enough rep points to chat, unfortunately. so i read the new latter half. i actually had thought of a much simpler way to achieve the same effect with less code if i do choose to do that (i.e. subtract the "door frame fill" of doors that open _into_ rooms). this can be achieved with JS by simply making an array of said "doors/door fills" and then changing the `color` to `#fff` and the `opacity` to `1`.  here's an updated version of the blueprint if you're interested: https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/GrzmGM i am still gon try and implement `<defs><path></defs><use></use>` fr doors&mom lines&etc

Comment: Hey Andrew, would you mind taking a look at another question I posted concerning a very similar issue. [Here is the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475582/use-member-element-of-group-to-clip-other-element)